# collect does not work with fraction

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

The third line in the following code does what I want, the second simply does nothing. Why is that? Is there an option I am missing to make a simple collect behave like the third line or - even better - work recursively through all fractions in the term?

```
a = (1 - r) (1 + r)/((r + p) (r + q));
Collect[a, r]
Collect[Numerator[a], r]/Collect[Denominator[a], r]
```

Comment: `Collect[]` is really intended for polynomials and not rational functions, so it makes sense to apply the thing to the numerators and denominators of your rational functions if that is what you need.